# Laravel trans() in trans() OR __() in __(). Is it possible?

Tags: php, laravel, localization

So I'm trying Laravel 9 localization with parameters in a controller response basicly like this:

```
return redirect()->route('index')->with('success', __('messages_success', ['name' => 'Fleet']));
```

On my `resources/lang/en.json`:

```
{
    "message_success_create":":Name created successfully.",
    "message_success_update":":Name updated successfully.",
    "message_success_delete":":Name deleted successfully.",
}
```

It works like a charm.

Suddenly I got a devil whisper like "I'm 100% sure that I can make it simpler & shorter!" then I changed those line in my controller to be:

```
return redirect()->route('index')->with('success', __('messages_success', ['name' => 'Fleet', 'action' => __('created')]));
```

In **resources/lang/en.json**:

```
{
    "message_success":":Name :action successfully.",
}
```

It got shorter and simpler right?
But **it doesn't work**! While it always successfully return text in default English but no other else.

Is this only on my machine or Laravel localization does not support **__()** in **__()** ?

I tried with **trans()** but no different.

Comment: The question is perfectly valid in technical terms, but you also need to ask yourself if the text is going to make sense in all target languages. It doesn't look unreasonable that a given language requires different genders or suffix or whatever. i18n is hard.